# Why WebFlux-WebClient Timeout not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using Spring boot Webflux 2.4.4 (latest) and trying to invoke a backend URL using WebClient. WebClient always responds above 20 secs. If I hit the URL directly it responds in milliseconds.

**Pom Looks below:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Code looks as Below:**

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Mono<String> test() {

        long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return webClient().get().uri("https://www.google.com").exchangeToMono(response -> {
            System.out.println("Elapsed Time is:  " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis));
            if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                return Mono.just("OK");
            }
            return Mono.just("OK");
        });
    }

    private WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient
                        .create().secure().responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3000).doOnConnected(c -> c
                                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(3)).addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(3)))))
                .build();
    }
}
```

1. The timeouts which I have configured seem no effect.
2. Why this takes 20 seconds to respond always.

Kindly suggest what I am missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

> The timeouts which I have configured seem no effect.

You've set a variety of arbitrary timeouts here, all that do different things:

- Your `ReadTimeoutHandler` is triggered when *no* data is read in the given time window. So if *any* data, however slow, is still being read in that 3 second window, it won't trigger.
- `WriteTimeoutHandler` gives a certain time window for a write to complete - but unless the underlying request that you're *sending* (not waiting for the response) takes more than that time, this won't trip either.
- `CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` is the time it takes to actually establish a TCP connection, before any data is sent. So again, unless that takes over 3 seconds, it won't trip.
- `responseTimeout()` is the time it takes to read a full response *after sending the request*. So note that this doesn't include any DNS resolution, warmup time, etc. that could be needed *before* the request is sent.

I'm not sure why it's taking over 20 seconds for you - that seems ridiculously long, the whole request executes on my moderately powered machine on my average internet connection in a few hundred ms at most. The cause of that could be anything from a very slow machine, slow internet connection, slow DNS servers, slow network, slow proxy, etc. - but it's not a problem with the code you have there.

If you want a timeout for the *whole* chain to execute, including any background requests, warmup time etc. that it might take - then AFAIK the only way of achieving that is on the mono itself - so your request then becomes:

```
return webClient()
    .get()
    .uri("https://www.google.com")
    .exchangeToMono(
        response -> {
          System.out.println("Elapsed Time is:  " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis));
          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return Mono.just("OK");
          }
          return Mono.just("OK");
        })
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500)); //Timeout specified here
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried from another machine, Its working as expected.

Comment: @Michael Berry, would `.timeout(Duration.ofMillis(500))` actually handle closing the connection at the TCP level as well?